# Example of using Prism 4 for Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, prism-4

Is there a simple example of using the Prism 4 MVVM framework for Windows Phone 7?

And the tests have written, and documentation -- but most important - **EXAMPLES** are absent.

P.S.
What are they thinking about???

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked this one http://wp7guide.codeplex.com/ ?

MS's developer guide (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx) put this sample as reference in their article.